# Check size of all keys in bytes in redis server

Tags: memory, redis, redis-server

How to check memory used by all the keys in redis-server.

I have started `redis-server` with `appendonly yes` option. To check size of an individual key I am using following commands-

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set foo bar
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> memory usage foo
(integer) 50
```

How do I get memory usage of all the existing keys in redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information using the following command:

```
 INFO memory
```

This will return detailed information about the memory usage and you can find the value:

- `used_memory_dataset`: The size in bytes of the dataset

You also have interesting values using the `MEMORY STATS` command, including the one describe above `dataset.bytes` and the total number of keys `keys.count`.

Also and probably my favorite approach, when I work with Redis I am using [Redis Insight](https://redislabs.com/redisinsight/) to look at all the metrics during development.

Regards

[Tug](https://twitter.com/tgrall)